# How to send large file as chunks via MCSession NSOutputStream

Tags: ios, iphone, sockets

I want to send large video file to connected peer in chunks via `NSOutputStream`

I am using below code.

```
NSError *error;
self.outputStream = [_appDelegate.mcManager.session startStreamWithName:@"Mystream" toPeer:[[_appDelegate.mcManager.session connectedPeers] objectAtIndex:0] error:&error];
```

At receiver side `NSStream` delegate not receiving entire send data.

```
-(void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode{

    switch(eventCode) {
        case  NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
            break;

        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
            if ([aStream isKindOfClass:[NSInputStream class]]) {

            }
            break;
        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:

            break;
        case NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable:
            break;
        case NSStreamEventNone:
            break;
        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
            break;
    }

}
```